# How to dismiss the UIPopoverController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have created a `UIPopoverController` and added it to a view controller when clicking an `UIButton` as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
}

- (IBAction)showPopover:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
               CGRect popRect = CGRectMake(self.btnShowPopover.frame.origin.x,
                                self.btnShowPopover.frame.origin.y,
                                self.btnShowPopover.frame.size.width,
                                self.btnShowPopover.frame.size.height);
          [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
    }
}
```

`btnShowPopover` is the `UIButton` in the `viewcontroller`, `popoverController` is the `UIPopoverController`.

The `popovercontroller` appears fine while clicking the button.

But it won't get dismissed when I click the `UIButton` in the `secondviewcontroller`

I used the following code for that

```
-(IBAction)y:(id)sender{
    fs =  [[Firstviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"FIrstscreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [fs.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

But it didn't work.

How to dismiss the `popovercontroller` when clicking the button in a viewcontoller that was added to the `popovercontroller`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are allocating a new instance of `Firstviewcontroller`, so it won't dismiss the previous instance's popover.

You need to pass the old instance when you are displaying the popover like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
    [controller setFs:self]
}
```

And dismiss like:

```
-(IBAction)y:(id)sender
{
    [fs.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: [controller setFs:self], it gives an error, How to pass the old instance when displaying the popover

Comment: @NAZIK: still have issues ?

Comment: @ Midhun MP, yes,error - popovercontroller not found on object of type 'PopOverViewController *'- what to do now?

Comment: @NAZIK: please check your code once again, I think you made a mistake. Check whether you are passing [... setFS:self] and check the typr of fs, it should be `Firstviewcontroller`

Comment: declare the fs in your SecondViewController class's @interface and create a property `@property (nonatomic, assign) Firstviewcontroller *fs;` if you are using non-arc and synthesize it

Comment: @NAZIK: my mistake, please check above comment. Type of fs is `Firstviewcontroller`

Comment: U said " Check whether you are passing [... setFS:self] and check the typr of fs" where to write this and what is 'setFS'

Comment: When writing [controller setFS:self]; it gives an error-  No visible @interface for 'PopoverViewController' declares the selector 'setFS:'

Comment: your `controller` is of type `SecondViewController` is it ?

Comment: I told you to put `@property (nonatomic, assign) Firstviewcontroller *fs;` this code on your `SecondViewController`'s `@interface`. Did you do that ?

Comment: yes I did it, and [fs.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:TRUE]; throws no error but it didnot dissmiss the popover

Comment: what is [controller setFs:self]

Comment: controller is the instance of your `SecondViewController` and you are setting the firstviewcontroller instance to fs using the setter method

Comment: @NAZIK: Ok, please share that

Comment: Hi Midhun, take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720228/calling-poptoviewcontroller-function-from-a-viewcontroller), pl answer if you can.

Comment: @NAZIK: I added a comment in your question, please check. It'll work. I think you already got that answer

Answer (score 4):

Apple docs:

> The popover controller does not call this method in response to programmatic calls to the `dismissPopoverAnimated:` method. If you dismiss the popover programmatically, you should perform any cleanup actions immediately after calling the dismissPopoverAnimated: method.

So the `didDimiss` delegate's method won't be called by itself.

Try:

```
[self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
[self.popover.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:self.PopUp];
```

Comment: it's not the case here, he is initializing new instance for dismissing the old popover