# Trying to dismiss table when a selection has been made in popup View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm calling this from my ViewController.m

When I've selected a row from the popup I'm trying to call the below controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ...

    TSPopoverController *dismiss = [[TSPopoverController alloc]init];
    [dismiss dismissPopoverAnimatd:YES];



}
```

Found in class: TSPopoverController.m

```
- (void) dismissPopoverAnimatd:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.view) {
        if(animated) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                  delay:0.0
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                             animations:^{
                                 popoverView.alpha = 0;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 [self.contentViewController viewDidDisappear:animated];
                                 popoverView=nil;
                                 [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                                 self.contentViewController = nil;
                                 self.titleText = nil;
                                 self.titleColor = nil;
                                 self.titleFont = nil;
                             }
             ];
        }else{
            [self.contentViewController viewDidDisappear:animated];
            popoverView=nil;
            [self.view removeFromSuperview];
            self.contentViewController = nil;
            self.titleText = nil;
            self.titleColor = nil;
            self.titleFont = nil;
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to call the method:

```
- (void) dismissPopoverAnimatd:(BOOL)animated
```

Nothing happens. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to get this popOverView to disappear when I have made my selection in the popovertable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are instantiating the popover again in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Instead you should create a member and use it to dismiss. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317252/how-to-dismiss-the-uipopovercontroller).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding:

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{  
    TSPopoverController *popoverController;   
}
```

Then I just called this in the below function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ...

    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimatd:YES];

}
```

Thanks for steering me in the right direction @xoail!